# python2 and python3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, atom-editor

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 which came with Python 3.7.6 installed. I installed Atom v1.45, which comes with Python 2.7 automatically.

When running a Python script from the terminal, it raises `ModuleNotFoundError`. I figured that if I ran the script from the terminal with `python3.7 file.py` instead of `python file.py` there is no problem, though it is slightly annoying to do that all the time.

I uninstalled python2.7 but then I could not use Atom.

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a very similar problem. Some of the tips from my end are:

1. I recommend using a virtual environment when running scripts from the command-line. This helps resolve all module dependencies for the script in general and especially when dealing with multiple Python versions.

   ```
   $ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 ./venv    
   $ source ./venv/bin/activate    
   $ ./venv/bin/python foo.py
   ```

   Typically, the above steps, are either in my Makefile or in a helper script.
2. When running a script from the terminal, if you want to type `python` instead of `python3.7`, you can create a symlink for `python` to point to `python3` in the `/usr/bin` directory.

Also, I recommend switching to `python3` completely since support for `python2.7` has officially stopped.